# UWP MVVM Multiframe navigation

Tags: mvvm, uwp, navigation, frame

My app contains two Frames in one window (FirstFrame & SecondFrame).
When I try to navigate in FirstFrameViewModel with navigationService.navigateTo(AnotherView) AnotherView fills the entire window instead of filling only FirstFrame.
How I can resolve my problem?

Comment: Can you please share your XAML code and the code you use for navigation. It'll be easier for us to help out and Are you using template 10 or some other framework?

Comment: @iam.Carrot I'm using MVVM Light

Comment: Well I know the issue what's happening. The issue is, when you call `navigationService.navigateTo(AnotherView)` it's binded to the `Modal` that is containing the two Frames. So when you see the new screen popping up it's hosted on the root modal instead of the Frames that you've defined. Now I can help you out with code of you can provide me with a basic sample project that show cases what you're trying to do. Put   it on github if you can

Comment: @iam.Carrot https://1drv.ms/i/s!AnI1_b7STHg2h8tUxZhQxyKVz4O9Dg 
A simple scheme. I drew.

Comment: I would prefer a simple demo project. I already understand your issue. I want to get a demo solution so that I can simply edit the code and return back instead of writing a solution from scatch